# Adding Python .conf format to INI plugin in sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, ini

I have added:

```
    <string>conf</string>
```

to `fileTypes` section (https://github.com/clintberry/sublime-text-2-ini/blob/master/INI.tmLanguage) for INI plugin but .conf files (which are essentially .ini files) are still not syntax highlighted in ST2.

I'd add ticket in INI plugin github Issues system but it seems to be abandonware...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a `.conf` file in Sublime, then select `View -> Syntax -> INI` for syntax highlighting. Then, select `View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as... -> INI` and you should be all set. This creates a file `Packages/User/INI.sublime-settings` with the correct settings in it:

```json
{
    "extensions":
    [
        "conf"
    ]
}
```